# Consulta MySQL con medoo

Tags: php, mysql

**Situación**

Me dispongo a pasar un proyecto que utiliza consultas mysql obsoletas ( del estilo de `mysql_query` o `mysql_connect`) al framework `Medoo` para que funcione correctamente en PHP7.

**Problema**

No estaba muy familiarizado con este framework, y haciendo unas pruebas previas me he encontrado con este problema; he creado una función que recibe el nombre de una tabla, el nombre de un campo y un número de id. Devuelve el valor del campo que recibe.

Voy a omitir la parte de la conexión con la base de datos porque ya he comprobado su correcto funcionamiento:

```
function devuelve_dato_sql($tabla, $campo, $id) {
    global $db;

    $data=$db->select($tabla,$campo,
        ['AND' => ['id' => $id]
        ]
    );
    return $data[0][$campo];
}

//Llamada a la función
$data=devuelve_dato_sql("usuarios","nombre","1");
echo $data; // "S"
var_dump($data); // string(1) "S"
```

El problema, como veis en los comentarios, es que en vez de devolverme el nombre completo, sólo recibo el primer carácter, ¿Que estoy pasando por alto?

**Edición**

He intentado poner la etiqueta de medoo pero no puedo ya que no existe y todavía no tengo la reputación necesaria para crearla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Solucionado!

En el return de la función tenía esto:

`return $data[0][$campo];`

Cuando la sintaxis correcta sería:

`return $data[0];`